# How can i display Admob banners in SFSafariViewcontroller?

Tags: swift, admob, sfsafariviewcontroller

I am developing an app in SWIFT 2.0 to open external websites within my app by using SFSafariViewcontroller. Since im using Admob for displaying ads within my app , i want to know if there is anyway i can show the banners on top of  SafariViewController webapages.

Comment: I have never used SafariViewController before, but can't you just `view.addSubView(adBanner)`?

Comment: I am now faced with this same question. Did you find an answer?

Comment: I was not able to find away to do this. Apparently Apple does not allow developers to add subviews to SafariViewController.